# Angular 8 ng2-chart error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at ChartElement.update

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at ChartElement.update (Chart.js:11474)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7127)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
    at fitBoxes (Chart.js:7145)
```

And I ran out of ideas to solve this question, I created a new project (Angular 8 & 9), displaying only the chart and it works fine, but when it's in my application, this fixBoxes function start an infinity loop.

Debugging the Chart.js I found out this infinity loop is caused by some NaN values, but I can't figure out how to set them, neither why they're Nan once this works fine in another project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `ChartComponent` is a child component, so when the function `fitBoxes` was trying to get some parameters such as width, it couldn't get any because the parent component was not fully loaded yet. So I used a `*ngIf` to only load the `ChartComponent` after its parent was loaded.

Comment: Could you add a bit more details on this? I don't know how to make the *ngIf-load.